# FragmentTransaction behaving differently for different android sdk releases

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I am working on an android project with this in `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.+'
}
```

I have a class called `HistoryFragment.java` in it

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecentHistoryPagerAdapter historyPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager, container, false);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            historyPagerAdapter = new HistoryPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
            viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(historyPagerAdapter);
            setTabListeners();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    public void viewSummary () {
        HistoryFragment historyFragment = (HistoryFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.hide(historyFragment);
        
        SummaryFragment summaryFragment = SearchResultSummaryFragment.newInstance();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, summaryFragment, "summaryFragment");
        transaction.commit();
        return;
```

here,

```
HistoryPagerAdapter extends android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
```

It works correctly and results in this.

[image: expected behavior]

I copied this to another project with this in its `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
}
```

It behaves incorrectly. While `SummaryFragment` does show up, it retains `historyPagerAdapter` as we can see in this next image

[image: unexpected behavior]

Comment: The `android.support` classes are all deprecated, no longer receiving bug fixes or new features, and should not be used in new code.  You should [migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).  There have been _many_ Fragment bugs fixed since the version you're on.  I don't know if this is one of them, but it would be the first thing I'd try, since you're using very outdated code.

Comment: Why not you using `androidx.*` api instead of `android.support.*`?? `android.*` is more easy and robust unified api

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in the comments, I would also recommend to switch your project to AndroidX libraries. This can be easily done by right-clicking on your module (In the Project pane), then select `Refactor...` and then `Migrate to AndroidX...`

Android Studio will then replace your gradle dependencies with the new androidx dependencies and change all `import` statements accordingly. I have done this also with big multi-module projects and it worked almost perfectly everytime. Maybe you have to adjust an import here and there.

Specific to your question, the new grade dependency for fragments is `implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'` (without the "-ktx" if you are using Java).

You should not and you cannot mix `android.support` with `anroidx.`. It's either the one or the other. Both together do not work!

You can find an overview of all new dependencies here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

Comment: That did not work for me. Additionally, I'm using `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`, and use a lot of methods that are now deprecated. One such method is `getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(android.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` Do I have any option except refactoring it?